# XML removeChild, but out output has a blank row

Tags: perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

Simple removeChild test, although the xml line is removed, it maintains an empty blank row, how come? Btw - my source xml file does have indents, however even when I remove them I get the same result.  So what's the point of being able to removeChild row if it still retains a blank space?

Is there a way to re-format the resulting xml lines prior to outputing it to the file?

```
foreach my $XYZ ($doc->findnodes("//EE1"))
{
 my $library = $XYZ->parentNode;
 $library->removeChild($XYZ);
} 
print {$FH} $doc->toString(0);



RESULT IN OUTPUT FILE:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TopTag>
  <AA1>ZNY</AA1>
  <AA2>111</AA2>
  <BB1>
    <CC1>ZNY</CC1>
    <CC2>
      <DD1>
                     <-----blank line remains
        <EE2>2000</EE2>
      </DD1>
      <DD1>
                     <-----blank line remains
        <EE2>5000</EE2>
      </DD1>
    </CC2>
  </BB1>
  <AA1>ZNY2</AA1>
  <AA2>2</AA2>
</TopTag>
```

Answer (score 5):

The empty lines come from text nodes containing whitespace. Consider the following document:

```
<doc>
  <elem/>
</doc>
```

The `doc` element contains the following nodes:

- A text node containing a newline and two space characters.
- An element node with the `elem` element.
- Another text node containing a newline.

If the `elem` element is removed, only the text nodes remain resulting in a blank line.

The easiest way to reindent a `XML::LibXML` document is to use the module `XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint`. Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215316/how-can-i-auto-indent-xml-nodes-with-xmllibxml).

Comment: thanks for the response ... Help me out here ... you say "a text node containing a newline and two two space characters" ... exactly where are these? I'm guessing the newline is right after the <doc> on the first line and the two space is before the <elem/> on the second line... but here's my confusion: I used my $parser->keep_blanks(0), and when I write to a file, there's no xtra whitespace - it's just one continuous line (in one row).

Comment: Also when I add use XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint; is says not avail. on the target platform (just like the other poster mentions in your link), and I don't/can't add this module to the all the workstations that the script is going to run on. I made use of XML::Twig's pretty_print, but now I have a sceanrio where I'm using two different parsers (XML's vs. Twig). So my next question is ...

Can I easily switch between two parsers within the script?

Comment: I was able to use Twig, but I had to go about it the long way ... I had to first writeout the file from XML, then open it using Twig's method and using pretty_print => 'indent' ... this worked as far as getting a formatted out file with indents (and removal of empty rows), but it seems convoluted.

Comment: If you use `$parser->keep_blanks(0)`, writing the document with `$doc->toString(1)` should work.

Comment: Ok, Ok, sorry for answering my own post ...
So sticking exclusively with LibXML (no Twig stuff)
If I add $parser->keep_blanks(0); , when it comes time to printout to file I include print {$FH} $doc->toString(1); will get my disired output, i.e. no blank rows and properly indented (regardless of whitespaces in source file).

Answer (score 0):

Remove newlines that are preceded by another newline (positive look-behind assertion) and optional whitespace in between.

```
my $output = $doc->toString(0);
$output =~ s/(?<=\n)\s*\n//g;
print {$FH} $output;
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to change the string by hand. This code for example will also remove non-optional newlines in text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `no_blanks` option for `load_xml()` - it will automatically strip any extra whitespace elements when importing your XML:

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename, no_blanks => 1);
```

Since the whitespace is removed, you need to then use:

```
print $dom->toString(1);
```

to get nicely formatted output.